# [Flutter]: Searching not working in SelectFormField package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Using this flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/select_form_field

Hello I am having an issue regarding searching in "SelectFormFieldType.dialog", I don't know if I have missed something but it seems like the search doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

List of items:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = [
    {
      'value': '',
      'label': 'Select Account',
      'icon': Icon(Icons.account_balance)
    },
    {'value': '1', 'label': 'Account 1', 'icon': Icon(Icons.account_balance)},
    {'value': '2', 'label': 'Account 2', 'icon': Icon(Icons.account_balance)},
    {'value': '3', 'label': 'Account 3', 'icon': Icon(Icons.account_balance)}
  ];
```

Here is selectformfield:

```
SelectFormField(
              dialogCancelBtn: 'Cancel',
              enableSearch: true,
              dialogSearchHint: 'Search account',
              type: SelectFormFieldType.dialog,
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
              labelText: 'Select Account',
              hintText: 'Select Account',
              items: _items,
              onChanged: (val) {
                print(val);
                },
            )
```

Here is the screenshot of the list
[list of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72vU2.png)

Here is the screenshot of output when searching item
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6ZWw.png)

Comment: maybe that's because the first item in your list is empty value

Comment: no that's not why because even with no empty value, the problem still persists